# Parsing API response in Xamarin form

Tags: xamarin

I am new to xamarin. I am trying to get data from php api but it doesn't give me any data or error kindly check. URL is
    http://mehdibalti.000webhostapp.com/xamrin/getall.php

```
response is .. [{"Id":"1","Name":"Mehdi","Department":"Balti"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Mehdi","Department":"Syntecx"}]

and i did like this 



  public class EmployeeServices
    {
        public EmployeeServices()
        {
        }


        public async Task<List<EmployeeModel>>  getEmployeeAsyn(){




            RestClient<EmployeeModel> resclient = new RestClient<EmployeeModel>();

            var list =await resclient.GetTodoItemsAsync();
            return list;

        }

    }
}
```

this is my resClient Class

```
        public async Task<List<EmployeeModel>> GetTodoItemsAsync()
        {

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();


            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(getAllUrl);


            response = response.Replace("\"", "");


            var todoItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeModel>>(response);



            return todoItems;

        }
```

this is Model class
 public class EmployeeModel

```
{

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Department { get; set; }
}


but it did not return any list
```

Answer (score 1):

The result API is giving you is not a list. Use stuff like http://json2csharp.com/
to investigate json you are getting.

Comment: json2csharp convert same as this

Comment: public class RootObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}

Comment: i think its same as my EmployeeModel

Comment: i think List<EmployeeModel> is not EmployeeModel

Comment: public class RestClient<T>
    {
        private const string getAllUrl = "http://mehdibalti.000webhostapp.com/xamrin/getall.php";

        public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            string json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(getAllUrl);
           // json = json.Replace("\"", "");

       var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

            return taskModels;
        }